# updatePanel with animation scripts

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Ive got div and change its content depending on which li element I click. I use updatePanel to change div content. I wonder if its possible to acheive nice jquery animations fade outs fade ins and so on using this technique.

Thanks for any suggestions and help,
bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of tutorial online for this:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_webforms_UpdatePanel_Animation.ashx

http://marriedgeek.com/2009/07/jquery-animation-updatepanel/

Answer (score -1):

Update panels do a full (well, almost) postback and reload the content of the panel.  You should be able to add your fades to the panel, but be aware that you're dealing with new content in the panel each time, so your methods would have to be called from inside the panel...